# Working with dependency injection in mvc

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

In one of our app I am already using the dependency injection of `AppTenant` class like follows

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddMultitenancy<AppTenant, CachingAppTenantResolver>();
services.Configure<MultitenancyOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Multitenancy"));
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
 app.UseMultitenancy<AppTenant>();
}
```

and in controller i am able to access it easily as follows

```
public AccountController(AppTenant tenant)
    {
        this.tenant = tenant;
    }
```

Now, I want to access the same `AppTenant` OR `HttpContext` in other project class in the same solution.
So, I have tried like this

```
public SqlStringLocalizerFactory(
       AppTenant tenant)
    {
     _tenant = tenant;

    }
```

But it is coming null, so what I need to do, to get the `AppTenant` OR `HttpContext` in the other project class ?

For `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` class the services are written in `ConfigureServices` method like follows

```
public static class SqlLocalizationServiceCollectionExtensions
{

    public static IServiceCollection AddSqlLocalization(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        return AddSqlLocalization(services, setupAction: null);
    }

   public static IServiceCollection AddSqlLocalization(
        this IServiceCollection services,
       Action<SqlLocalizationOptions> setupAction)
    {

            if (services == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(services));
        }

        services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(
            typeof(IStringExtendedLocalizerFactory),
            typeof(SqlStringLocalizerFactory),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
        services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(
            typeof(IStringLocalizerFactory),
            typeof(SqlStringLocalizerFactory),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton));
        services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(
            typeof(IStringLocalizer),
            typeof(SqlStringLocalizer),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton));

        if (setupAction != null)
        {
            services.Configure(setupAction);
        }
        return services;
    }
}
```

I have even tried with `IHttpContextAccessor`, but still not getting any success.

Any help on this appreciated !

Comment: Did you configure/add `IHttpContextAccessor` to services. It is not automatically added. you will have to add it manually in order for services to be aware of it. ie `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Comment: You've registered `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` as *singleton* so there will only be one for the lifetime of your app. The singleton lifestyle does not match the lifetime of `HttpContext` which is *per request* and leaves you with a **captive dependency**.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes I have added and in the class I have written as `private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor         public SqlStringLocalizerFactory(
IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)`

Comment: @qujck So how do I need to register `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` class ? With `AddScoped` OR `AddTransient` ?

Comment: @Rohit sorry I can't help you there, I've not invested in .NET Core DI

Comment: @Nikosi Yes I have tried with this.. But `IHttpContextAccessor` is resolved as `NULL`..why it is so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit-2**

New Solution:

```
public SqlStringLocalizerFactory(IHttpContextAccessor _accessor)
{
   _accessor= accessor;
}
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var tenant = _accessor.HttpContext.RequestServices
            .GetRequiredService<AppTenant>();
}
```

**Edit** : `IServiceProvider` way doesn't work as i expect. See @Sock's solution

First, i assumes the problem occurs because of captive dependency as pointed by @qujck. To avoid captive dependency:

If lifetime of `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` must be singleton(some cases must be), in this
   case use `IServiceProvider`:

```
public SqlStringLocalizerFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
   _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var tenant =  _serviceProvider.GetService<AppTenant>();
}
```

Otherwise using `AddScoped` seems reasonable for your case.

Comment: In this case, if the `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` is registered as a singleton, the `AppTenant` being resolved from the `IServiceProvider` will be singleton scoped too according to this twitter exchange: https://twitter.com/julielerman/status/761179861935394817

Comment: I assumes `SomeMethod` will be called in a request scope because it needs `AppTenant`(not in the `ConfigureServices` etc.). In this case i think `IServiceProvider` resolves right `AppTenant`. Am i wrong?

Comment: Event though you are calling `SomeMethod` in the context of a request, if the `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` is registered as a singleton, the `IServiceProvider` that is injected will create objects of Singleton scope. So every call you make to `_serviceProvider.GetService<AppTenant>();` will return the same `AppTenant` instance, even though `AppTenant` is registered as `Scoped`. In order to make the `AppTenant` have a scoped lifetime, you need to use the `ServiceScopeFactory` as shown below.

Comment: If you ues this approach (edit 2), be aware that you must explicitly register the `IHttpContextAccessor` in your services using `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`. It is no longer registered by default due to 'non-trivial performance costs'. See https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793

Comment: @ademcaglin I have tried with `IHttpContextAccessor` and `IServiceProvider` but both are coming null. Yes, I am using 'Saaskit.Multitenancy'

Comment: Did you register `IHttpContextAccessor` explicitly as pointed in previous Sock's comment? Try  `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

Comment: @Rohit Could you post current code what you are trying? Just ConfigureServices and SqlStringLocalizerFactory is enough.

Comment: @ademcaglin Its resolved.. thanks.. Initially haven't registered it properly.. now registered properly and its working.. thanks a lot for the help ! Upvoted !

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, the best option, if the `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` can be a scoped dependency (you get a new instance for every request) then you can register it as a scoped dependency:

```
services.TryAdd(new ServiceDescriptor(
        typeof(IStringLocalizerFactory),
        typeof(SqlStringLocalizerFactory),
        ServiceLifetime.Scoped));
```

If the `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` *must* be a a Singleton dependency, then you need to make sure you resolve a scoped dependency for the Tenant by using a `ServiceSope`:

```
public class SqlStringLocalizerFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public SqlStringLocalizerFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        using (var serviceScope = _serviceProvider
            .GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var tenant = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<AppTenant>();

            // do something with tenant...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested your solution, if AppTenant is resolved before calling `SomeMethod`,    two different AppTenant is created for same request. It might be a problem.

Comment: This is true, depending on how the AppTenant itself is resolved I think. In SaasKit, the tenant is resolved once per requests and stored in the `HttpContext.Items` property. When it is injected via DI, the `AppTenant` from the `HttpContext` is returned. In that case, resolving it more than once will still return the same object. However, if a new object is resolved every time it is injected, then you are correct.

Comment: @Sock Thanks for the reply. I have tried your solution but 'IServiceProvider' is coming `NULL`

Comment: I think maybe you have a problem with the location where you are using `SqlStringLocalizerFactory`. I tested this solution injecting it into a controller and it worked as expected. I note you have also added  a comment above saying you can't resolve `IHttpContextAccessor` either - this suggests to me you're not using `SqlStringLocalizerFactory` in the context of a request. Is that the case?